# How portable is relying on scrrun.dll being available?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, typelib

I have the following directive in my sources:

`#import <scrrun.dll>`

Can I rely on this DLL being pre-installed with Windows?

How relying on this limits Windows versions, which can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking us to predict what a very large company like Microsoft is going to do in the, what, next 10 years.  Impossible to answer accurately of course.

Nevertheless, the scripting runtime is available in the latest version of Windows, got ported to 64-bits, has no obscure or desperately ancient or deprecated dependencies.  It is used in many programs.  Microsoft has a very strong commitment to app-compat.

Odds are very good that you are not going to have to worry about it for a long time.

Comment: No, no predictions - just for existing production versions of Windows, from XP up to - what they have now? - Windows 2008?